# C# - Property Clarification

Tags: c#, interface, properties

According to the definition :

***"As interface is not an object by itself ,I can't initialize it.If interface were allowed to declare fileds, then it needs storage location,so we can not declare fields inside interface."***

Incase of property  say example

when i declare

```
 string SayHello { get; set; }
```

inside the interface

It is internally hooked as   `get_SayHello( )  ,set_SayHello()` in IL   (when i disassemble i 
can see the get and set methods).

***My question is still property needs some storage location,then how the property declaration***

is allowed inside the interface.

Edit :
This is what i understood.As I am new to C#,i am seeking your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're operating on a somewhat faulty assumption, that properties require a backing field.  Yes **most** properties use a backing field but this is certainly not a requirement.  I can for instance implement your interface with no backing field as follows

```
class C1 : IFoo {
  public string SayHello {
    get { return "Say Hello"; }
    set { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The declaration of a property in an interface says that any implementing class must have such methods (`get_SayHello` and `set_SayHello` but defined as properties) but does not specify how they are implemented. That is, the interface says what you can do, but now how it is done (so you can get the `SayHello` "string", and you can set the `SayHello` "string"). So, to be specific: defining a property in an interface says nothing about backing fields.

Also, it is a misconception that properties have to have backing fields. The following does not:

```
class Example {
    public string SayHello {
        get {
            return "Hello, World!"; 
        } 
        set { }
    }
}
```

Properties are just methods that are accessible via field-like syntax. As they are methods, and not fields, they are defineable an interface.

Answer (score 4):

As Jared says, the property doesn't necessarily need any storage location... but you're still overthinking it, I believe.

Imagine your interface was actually:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   string get_SayHello();
   string set_SayHello(string value);
}
```

Just methods in an interface. Are you happy with that? If so, that really is all the property is, along with a bit of metadata to tie those methods together. Nothing to do with fields... just methods.

The *implementer* might want to use a field, but that's entirely separate from the interface.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring such a property in an interface simply means that any classes you define that implement the interface are required to implement that property.  Those classes are free to implement the property in any way you see fit (either as automatic properties, or through some other more complex means).

Changing your property in the interface to the following:

```
string SayHello { get; }
```

The implementing classes are only required to implement the getter for that property.  But no storage allocation is taking place at the interface level.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is still property needs
>   some storage location

That is not true. You can do whatever you want in getters/setters. By declaring a property in an interface, you just force implementers to provide a getter and/or a setter.

Answer (score 2):

Not all .NET languages have the concept of properties.  So the interfaces must also define get_ and set_ versions of the property so that any .NET language can use the type.  This might be adding to your confusion.

Comment: How can a language not have a concept of a property, given that having a read/write property in .net is (alas) different semantically from having a read-only property and also having a write-only property?  For example, given `IReadableFoo`, with read-only property `Foo`, and `IWritableFoo`, with a like-named write-only property, an interface `IReadWriteFoo` which inherits both must, to be useful, define a third read-write property.  How would one do that in a language which didn't understand properties?

Comment: @supercat: I don't see how that's related to this (awful) answer (which I will be deleting soon) or the question.  Your question is answered in part by "CLS Compliance", and in part by "the hell are you smoking?".

Comment: If a language doesn't know about properties, is there any way by which it could be used to write an implementation of an interface which contains one?

Answer (score 1):

Well a declaration inside an interface just tells you what members can be expected to exist on an instance of that interface. It tells you nothing about how they are implemented or where they are saved.

I think you have confused the concept of a interface with that of a class. You don't instantiate interfaces, but classes that implement them.